# Postion: Absolute not working properly

Tags: html, css

What i'm trying to do is (in css):

- Make the test1 ID absolute to the sidebar ID
- Make the test2 ID absolute to logo
- test1 got position:absolute
- test2 got position:absolute
- sidebar got position:absolute
- logo got position:absolute

The test1 is working fine inside the sidebar
But the logo id gets positioned absolute to sidebar. The test2 should be absolute to logo, but logo shouldnt be absolute to sidebar.

Is there a fix for this? Joey.

```
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <a href="https://google.com/" target="blank">
            <div id="test1"></div>
        </a>
    </div>

        <div id="logo">
            <div id="test2">
        </div>

</body>
```

Comment: div test2 does not close

Comment: could you replicate your problem within a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If all container got `position:absolute;` then make a outer container with `position:relative;` then add `top:x; left:y;` to the absolute container's css where x and y are pixel values... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

solution

http://jsfiddle.net/yWDNJ/1/

```
#test1, #test2 {
    position:absolute;
}
#siderbar, #logo {
    position:relative;
}
```

also as i said in comment, your div test2 needs to close